# Finding absolute extreme values on a region D

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I am unable to understand how to use lagrange multipliers in this question. Can you lead me a way to solve this question?
I've always used lagrange multipliers with circles; however, in this case, it is an ellipsis. I am unsure about how to apply lagrange multipliers on ellipsis.

Question: Function: $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \:x^3-\frac{1}{4}\cdot \:x+y^2$

Find the absolute extreme values on the region $D$:
$$D=\left\{\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\left(x-1\right)^2+4y^2\le 4 \right\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step: determine the critical points of $f$ in the interior of $D$ and investigate their nature (lokal max, local min, saddle point).

Second step: investigate the function $F$ on $ \partial D.$ The Lagrange function is:

$$L(x,y, \mu)=f(x,y) - \mu( (x-1)^2+4y^2-4).$$

Comment: Solved it by doing something else, but thanks for looking out.